# Access Link Text Wizard - Syntax error in PARAMETER clause

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to link to a text file from the Access **Link Text Wizard** (as I've successfully done hundreds of times before) but this time I'm getting an error stating

> Syntax error in PARAMETER clause.

No parameterized query is being used so I'm at a bit of a loss, I'm only trying to link to a text file.

In Access 2016 I go to the **External Data** tab and click **Text File**. I browse to my tab-delimited text file and select the **Link to the data source creating a linked table** option. As soon as I click OK it gives me the error above.

My text file is very simple with 2 columns and about 100 rows of data. This file is created from a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2016 using BCP. If I manually create a text file with test data using the same format I don't get the error, which leads me to believe it may be some data in the file causing the error? I can't figure out how to attach text files to my question so any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: I copied all data from the offending file into a new text file and it linked properly so it's not the data. I am often creating text files from a SQL Server Stored Procedure then linking to it from Access. This is the first time I've experienced this particular error.

EDIT2: I recreated a text file manually with the same data from the offending file and named it the same this time (Procedure Class Listing.txt) and I got the error. Is something wrong with this title???

EDIT3: Sorry for so many edits. I tried naming the file without the spaces and it links properly. I have linked to files with spaces in the name before so I don't understand.

FINAL EDIT: So it appears that a text file starting with the word "Procedure" followed by a space is giving me this error. I can remove all spaces (ProcedureClassListing.txt) and it works fine (which is the solution I'm going with).

Comment: Wild guess: the reserved word `class` in the name? Although I don't see why the file name should matter.

Comment: It does appear something in the name is causing the error. I tried various combos of the 3 words (Procedure Class Listing) and found it also throws the error when named "Procedure Class.txt". Procedure and Class alone didn't cause the error.

Comment: Actually any file name that is 2 words and starts with "Procedure" is giving me the error. I'll chalk it up to the fact it doesn't like keywords in the file name and will close the question.

Comment: Actually this would be worth a self-answer instead of closing, IMO. While very obscure, someone else may stumble on the same problem in the future.

Comment: I agree with you @Andre. I posted an answer myself. I didn't want to delete it because I did not find one other example of someone else having this specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that a file starting with the word "Procedure" followed by a space is giving me this error. I can remove all spaces (ProcedureClassListing.txt) and it works fine (which is the solution I'm going with).